# After Install of SSDT 2015, SSDT 2010 no longer works

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I just installed SSDT 2015 and it appears to be working fine. I went into SSDT 2010 and tried to create a data flow with a flat file source and got the following message. I also tried a sql server connection and got the same problem.

```
===================================

The component could not be added to the Data Flow task.
Could not initialize the component. There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Component ", clsid {E32A96E1-7118-4CB5-A338-AC69E815CB13}" could not be created and returned error code 0x80070005 "Access is denied.". Make sure that the component is registered correctly.

Error at Data Flow Task [ [9]]: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "".



===================================

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0048021 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.CManagedComponentWrapperClass.ProvideComponentProperties()
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineTaskDesigner.AddNewComponent(String clsid, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean select)
```

I tried setting the run64bitruntime to false, but that didn't help.

Comment: Why do you want to use SSDT2010 if you installed SSDT2015? SSDT2015 can write SSIS packages for versions 2012, 2014 and 2016 - it's up to you.